# How to make a left join in django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models and I need to do a left join operation
I tried some solutions, but wihout success yet

Models

```
class SmdRepairIn(models.Model):
    sum_ymd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    line_nm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    model_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class SmdRepairOut(models.Model):  
    repair_in_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  
    repairman_out = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

SMDRepairIn.id == SmdRepairOut.repair_in_id

I want to retrieve the correspondent query result:

```
select A.*, B.repairman_out 
from SmdRepairIn as A
     left join (select repairman_out from SmdRepairOut) B on (A.id = B.repair_in_id )
```

How to do it in django queryset?

The expected result should be:

id, sum_ymd, line_nm, model_code, repairmain_out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Foreignkey` already in the model:

```
class SmdRepairIn(models.Model):
    sum_ymd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    line_nm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    model_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class SmdRepairOut(models.Model):  
    repair_in = models.ForeignKey(SmdRepairIn, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)  
    repairman_out = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

(Note: you should rethink whether there is a SmdRepairOut without a SmdRepairIn. If not, the ForeignKey line should be `repair_in = models.ForeignKey(SmdRepairIn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`)

This will allow you to query for the selections you need. Examples see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Some examples:

```
SmdRepairIn.objects.all().values_list('sum_ymd', 'line_nm', 'model_code', 'smdrepairout__repairman_out')
```

This is close to what you were asking for. It uses a reverse lookup `smdrepairout__repairman_out`.

Other way around:

```
SmdRepairOut.objects.all().values_list('repairman_out', 'repair_in__sum_ymd')
```